# laravel models fill additional field inside many-to-many table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-migrations

I am a newbie at Laravel framework and trying to work me in.
I already understand how to generate N:M relationships and handle them inside the models. Now I am asking you how to fill an additional field inside the many to many tables?

For example:

- Table Foo
- Table User_Foo

  - user_id
  - foo_id
  - is_owner (bool)
- Table User

Now I want to declare which of the foo users is the real owner.
In my opinion, the N:M Table has stored this information an not the Foo itself.
So how is it possible to declare those additional fields inside of my Foo and User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve additional fields you can with withPivot() method

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('is_owner');
```

Fill you can with sync() or attach() methods.

[Laravel relations doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: really thank you about that :-) that works for me. The other post will work as well, but I marked that as working, because of the linking to the docs :-)

Comment: My pleasure) I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides us with concept of `pivot`when defining N-M relationships. By default the table will have the both connected keys. But if you want to add extra fields in that bridge table.

```
$model->belongsToMany('Model')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

In above case, your pivot table will have two additional columns and you can access these columns as:

```
$model->pivot->column1
$model->pivot->column2
```